# ReportViewer and DataSets - Error while Installing on Other PC

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, dataset, reportviewer

> Using: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. SQL Server 2008. Report Viewer
>   2010

Hey everybody, hope you doin' great!, i'm actually having a hard time going through a complicated moment at my thesis developing.

Okay, let me explain it to you.

I designed reports on my software, on localhost they work perfectly but when I tried installing the software on other computer I'm getting an error when trying to open one of the reports.

The error is not controlled by the application, it says something like
"Error related to the network while trying to stablish a connection with the SQL Server, the server couldn't be found or it was unreacheable."

The thing is, on the form I got the report I'm Filling the ReportViewer with this.

```css
this.UsuariosAtendidosTableAdapter.Fill(this.DB_SUBSIDIOS_MUNICIPALIDADDataSet.UsuariosAtendidos, fecha1, fecha2);
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

DB_SUBSIDIOS_MUNICIPALIDAD is my Database.
UsuariosAtendidos is my Procedure.
fecha1, and fecha2 are the two needed fields to fill the stored procedure.

Moving on, on my RDLC I'm calling the stored procedure from a DataSet which provides of all the procedures.

The thing is that when installing it on other computer it seems like it CANT or its UNABLE to access that DataSet because its on my computer.

So the questions are:
How am I supossed to fill the report without using a local dataset?

PS: Sorry for my bad english, isn't my fluent lenguage.

Answer (score 0):

You should also have a SQL Server instance with the database of interest on this another computer or you should change the connection string to point to your original computer, these two computers should be on the same network, SQL Server on the first computer must be started and available

Comment: Thanks for replying.
The SQL Server is started and available, I can do many tasks related with the SQL Server, but the only ones I cant execute are the Reports, which are linked to a dataset that can't be reached by other computers.

Comment: >>>I can do many tasks related with the SQL Server<<< So you can connect to this server from another pc? And what connection string do you use in this case?

Comment: Yes, it works fine, it's just the reports linked to datasets which aren't available because I programmed this on my PC, and the other clients gets like an unknown path they try to follow for the dataset... its weird, I dont know what to do.

BTW, I'm using a basic string connection from a notepad.

server=_______;user id=______; password=_______; database=_________

Comment: I was thinking, maybe I shouldn't be working with DataSets at all, Maybe I should fill the report in locale mode, but how to create a Tablix without being asked for a connection or dataset?

Comment: You should change the connection string to point to your server as you do in other cases when you say it works fine

Comment: that's the weird thing, everything connects to the server perfectly, but on the reports they won't use the connection string, they will try to connect to a 'non-existing-on-the-server-dataset' thing...

Comment: Post here your connection string, please